# How to make a file uploader (.jpg, .mp3, .pdf etc) from local directory for a user in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Need an idea about how we can get that file from the user that he has selected from the local directory and send it to database.

Comment: Look up how to handle a file upload in Django, then read that file into binary, then record the binary into the database.

Comment: with <input type="file" > ?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use the django FileField, this wont store the file in the database directly (would also cause problems with large files e.g. videos), but rather uploads the file to the server and stores the path in the database.

---

**EDIT:**

More infos about the `FileField` can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield). You will need to create a ModelField in your model and define the path, where the file should be stored via `upload_to`.

For the upload process itself you have to create a view (easiest way would be a `CreateView` (more infos [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview)). This would enable a user to access the page (view) and create a model instance with the desired file.

---

**EDIT2:**
You'll need a simple HTML-Form for this, the CreateView will provide it for you. In the template you can simply use:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

which will lead to

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="***">
    <input type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would suggest to you to have a look at Django / HTML basics.

Comment: Can you please explain with the code in more detail.

Comment: Maybe you getting wrong. I am talking about the code where you will select a file from the computer and that selected should remain in the process until I press the submit button on the form. Suppose you have to submit the resume, then you selected the file from local system and then that file should be there untill i hit submit. Getting my point?

Comment: have a look at the second edit, but as i mentioned, if you have a look at the create view documentation, there is a tutorial on how to create the corresponding forms